# Optimizing huge amounts of calls of fsolve in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I'm solving a pair of non-linear equations for each voxel in a dataset of a ~billion voxels using `fsolve()` in MATLAB 2016b.

[image: equation pair]

I have done all the 'easy' optimizations that I'm aware of. Memory localization is OK, I'm using `parfor`, the equations are in fairly numerically simple form. All discontinuities of the integral are fed to `integral()`. I'm using the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm with good starting values and a suitable starting damping constant, it converges on average with 6 iterations.

I'm now at ~6ms per voxel, which is good, but not good enough. I'd need a order of magnitude reduction to make the technique viable. There's only a few things that I can think of improving before starting to hammer away at accuracy:

The splines in the equation are for quick sampling of complex equations. There are two for each equation, one is inside the 'complicated nonlinear equation'. They represent two equations, one which is has a large amount of terms but is smooth and has no discontinuities and one which approximates a histogram drawn from a spectrum. I'm using `griddedInterpolant()` as the editor suggested.

Is there a faster way to sample points from pre-calculated distributions?

```
parfor i=1:numel(I1)
    sols = fsolve(@(x) equationPair(x, input1, input2, ... 
         6 static inputs, fsolve options)
    output1(i) = sols(1); output2(i) = sols(2)
end
```

When calling `fsolve`, I'm using the 'parametrization' suggested by Mathworks to input the variables. I have a nagging feeling that defining a anonymous function for each voxel is taking a large slice of the time at this point. Is this true, is there a relatively large overhead for defining the anonymous function again and again? Do I have any way to vectorize the call to `fsolve`?

There are two input variables which keep changing, all of the other input variables stay static. I need to solve one equation pair for each input pair so I can't make it a huge system and solve it at once. Do I have any other options than `fsolve` for solving pairs of nonlinear equations?

If not, some of the static inputs are the fairly large. Is there a way to keep the inputs as persistent variables using MATLAB's `persistent`, would that improve performance? I only saw examples of how to load persistent variables, how could I make it so that they would be input only once and future function calls would be spared from the assumedly largish overhead of the large inputs?

EDIT:

The original equations in full form look like:

[image: I_high]

[image: I_low]

Where:

[image: f_KN]

and:

[image: Alpha]

Everything else is known, solving for x_1 and x_2. f_KN was approximated by a spline. S_low (E) and S_high(E) are splines, the histograms they are from look like:

[image: Spectra]

Comment: Have you profiled your code? The  "run and time" button

Comment: Can you show us how you've implemented the "complicated nonlinear equation"?

Comment: Sure. All of the time of the main-method is spent on the line with fsolve(), with most of the time in the Levenberg-Marquardt, specifically computing finite differences and Jacobians. A bit over 50% of the time of the whole call is in the P-file finitedifferences. The function called by fsolve() has 7% of it's time in 'Self-time (overhead, etc)', can I take that as a sign that fooling around with persistent variables would not pay dividends?

Comment: The 'Self-time' of the main-method is at a neglible 0.02%, 99.5% of the time is at fsolve()

Comment: That's indeed usually the case; computing numerical derivatives normally constitute the majority of the cost. Perhaps you can reuse some data between calls, or derive an analytical gradient so that the whole derivative estimation can be skipped...I'd need to see that function.

Comment: I'm guessing the functions with the most amount of self-time are `spparms` and/or `spline`?

Comment: Is `E = E(x)`? Because if not, `x` is basically a constant in the integration and it is almost trivial to compute the gradient

Comment: I've added the original equations in full form.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132922/discussion-between-rody-oldenhuis-and-tapio).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there's a few things I thought of:

### Lookup table

Because the integrals in your function do not depend on any of the parameters other than `x`, you could make a simple 2D-lookup table from them:

```
% assuming simple (square) range here, adjust as needed
[x1,x2]  = meshgrid( linspace(0, xmax, N) );

LUT_high = zeros(size(x1));
LUT_low  = zeros(size(x1));

for ii = 1:N        

    LUT_high(:,ii) = integral(@(E) Fhi(E, x1(1,ii), x2(:,ii)), ...
                              0, E_high, ...
                              'ArrayValued', true);

    LUT_low(:,ii) = integral(@(E) Flo(E, x1(1,ii), x2(:,ii)), ...
                             0, E_low, ...
                             'ArrayValued', true);

end
```

where `Fhi` and `Flo` are helper functions to compute those integrals, vectorized with scalar `x1` and vector `x2` in this example. Set `N` as high as memory will allow.

Those lookup tables you then pass as parameters to `equationPair()` (which allows `parfor` to distribute the data). Then just use `interp2` in `equationPair()`:

```
F(1) = I_high - interp2(x1,x2,LUT_high, x(1), x(2));
F(2) = I_low  - interp2(x1,x2,LUT_low , x(1), x(2));
```

So, instead of recomputing the whole integral *every time*, you evaluate it once for the expected range of `x`, and reuse the outcomes.

You can specify the interpolation method used, which is `linear` by default. Specify `cubic` if you're really concerned about accuracy.

### Coarse/Fine

Should the lookup table method not be possible for some reason (memory limitations, in case the possible range of `x` is too big), here's another thing you could do: split up the whole procedure in 2 parts, which I'll call *coarse* and *fine*.

The intent of the **coarse** method is to improve your initial estimates *really* quickly, but perhaps not so accurately. The quickest way to approximate that integral *by far* is via the [rectangle method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method):

- do *not* approximate `S` with a `spline`, just use the original tabulated data (so `S_high/low = [S_high/low@E0, S_high/low@E1, ..., S_high/low@E_high/low]`
- At the same values for `E` as used by the `S` data (`E0`, `E1`, ...), evaluate the exponential at `x`:

  ```
  Elo = linspace(0, E_low, numel(S_low)).';
  integrand_exp_low = exp(x(1)./Elo.^3 + x(2)*fKN(Elo));

  Ehi = linspace(0, E_high, numel(S_high)).';
  integrand_exp_high = exp(x(1)./Ehi.^3 + x(2)*fKN(Ehi));
  ```

  then use the rectangle method:

  ```
  F(1) = I_low  - (S_low  * Elo) * (Elo(2) - Elo(1));
  F(2) = I_high - (S_high * Ehi) * (Ehi(2) - Ehi(1));
  ```

Running `fsolve` like this for all `I_low` and `I_high` will then have improved your initial estimates `x0` probably to a point close to "actual" convergence.

Alternatively, instead of the rectangle method, you use `trapz` ([trapezoidal method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule)). A tad slower, but possibly a bit more accurate.

Note that if `(Elo(2) - Elo(1)) == (Ehi(2) - Ehi(1))` (step sizes are equal), you can further reduce the number of computations. In that case, the first `N_low` elements of the two integrands are identical, so the values of the exponentials will only differ in the `N_low + 1 : N_high` elements. So then just compute `integrand_exp_high`, and set `integrand_exp_low` equal to the first `N_low` elements of `integrand_exp_high`.

The **fine** method then uses your original implementation (with the actual `integral()`s), but then starting at the updated initial estimates from the coarse step.

The whole objective here is to try and bring the total number of iterations needed down from about 6 to less than 2. Perhaps you'll even find that the `trapz` method already provides enough accuracy, rendering the whole **fine** step unnecessary.

### Vectorization

The rectangle method in the coarse step outlined above is easy to vectorize:

```
% (uses R2016b implicit expansion rules)

Elo = linspace(0, E_low, numel(S_low));
integrand_exp_low = exp(x(:,1)./Elo.^3 + x(:,2).*fKN(Elo));

Ehi = linspace(0, E_high, numel(S_high));
integrand_exp_high = exp(x(:,1)./Ehi.^3 + x(:,2).*fKN(Ehi));

F = [I_high_vector - (S_high * integrand_exp_high) * (Ehi(2) - Ehi(1))
     I_low_vector  - (S_low  * integrand_exp_low ) * (Elo(2) - Elo(1))];
```

`trapz` also works on matrices; it will integrate over each column in the matrix.

You'd call `equationPair()` then using `x0 = [x01; x02; ...; x0N]`, and `fsolve` will then converge to `[x1; x2; ...; xN]`, where `N` is the number of voxels, and each `x0` is 1×2 (`[x(1) x(2)]`), so `x0` is `N`×2.

`parfor` should be able to slice all of this fairly easily over all the workers in your pool.

Similarly, vectorization of the **fine** method should also be possible; just use the `'ArrayValued'` option to `integral()` as shown above:

```
F = [I_high_vector - integral(@(E) S_high(E) .* exp(x(:,1)./E.^3 + x(:,2).*fKN(E)),...
                              0, E_high,...
                              'ArrayValued', true);
    I_low_vector   - integral(@(E) S_low(E) .* exp(x(:,1)./E.^3 + x(:,2).*fKN(E)),...
                              0, E_low,...
                              'ArrayValued', true);
    ];
```

### Jacobian

Taking derivatives of your function is quite easy. [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+integral+g(y)+%2A+exp(x%2Fy%5E3+%2B+z%2Af(y))+dy) is the derivative w.r.t. `x_1`, and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdz+integral+g(y)+%2A+exp(x%2Fy%5E3+%2B+z%2Af(y))+dy) w.r.t. `x_2`. Your Jacobian will then have to be a 2×2 matrix

```
J = [dF(1)/dx(1)  dF(1)/dx(2)
     dF(2)/dx(1)  dF(2)/dx(2)];
```

Don't forget the leading minus sign (`F = I_hi/lo - g(x)` → `dF/dx = -dg/dx`)

Using one or both of the methods outlined above, you can implement a function to compute the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) and pass this on to `fsolve` via the `'SpecifyObjectiveGradient'` option ([via `optimoptions`)](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html#inputarg_options). The `'CheckGradients'` option will come in handy there.

Because `fsolve` usually spends the vast majority of its time computing the Jacobian via finite differences, manually computing a value for it manually will normally speed the algorithm up *tremendously*.

It will be faster, because

1. `fsolve` doesn't have to do extra function evaluations to do the finite differences
2. the convergence rate will increase due to the improved precision of the Jacobian

Especially if you use the rectangle method or `trapz` like above, you can reuse many of the computations you've already done for the function values themselves, meaning, even more speed-up.

Comment: I implemented the 'coarse' -method with a Jacobian with excellent results. Now the majority of the time is spent on overhead. Vectorization would be the remedy here, however I'm unable to implement it the way you describe it. No matter how I try to spin it around fsolve() apparently interperets a X times 2 array input X times 2 array output as a system of X times 2 dependant variables. i.e. it converges to a result which looks much like white noise instead of a image. Could you please verify that it's possible to vectorize X independent equation pairs with independent inputs and outputs?

Comment: @Tapio did you compare the course with fine method? `trapz` with rectangle method? How far off are the course and fine solutions on average?

Comment: @Tapio indeed, it was my intention to pass more than 2 dependent variables per pass. The for loop then passes "batches", rather than individual problems. See [this other answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41635918/how-to-iterate-over-functions/41637024#41637024) for an example of what I mean.

Comment: Practically the same! The measurement data and the simulations are all pretty coarse and discrete, so the end results look very much alike. Your second answer helped, I got it to work. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Rody's answer was the correct one. Supplying the Jacobian was the single largest factor. Especially with the vectorized version, there were 3 orders of magnitude of difference in speed with the Jacobian supplied and not.

I had trouble finding information about this subject online so I'll spell it out here for future reference: It is possible to vectorize independant parallel equations with fsolve() with great gains.

I also did some work with inlining fsolve(). After supplying the Jacobian and being smarter about the equations, the serial version of my code was mostly overhead at ~1*10^-3 s per voxel. At that point most of the time inside the function was spent passing around a options -struct and creating error-messages which are never sent + lots of unused stuff assumedly for the other optimization functions inside the optimisation function (levenberg-marquardt for me). I succesfully butchered the function fsolve and some of the functions it calls, dropping the time to ~1*10^-4s per voxel on my machine. So if you are stuck with a serial implementation e.g. because of having to rely on the previous results it's quite possible to inline fsolve() with good results.

The vectorized version provided the best results in my case, with ~5*10^-5 s per voxel.