# How to iterate over functions?

Tags: matlab, function, for-loop, iteration

I would like to apply loop over a function.  I have the following "mother" code:

```
v = 1;
fun = @root;
x0 = [0,0]
options = optimset('MaxFunEvals',100000,'MaxIter', 10000 );
x = fsolve(fun,x0, options)
```

In addition, I have the following function in a separate file:

```
function D = root(x)
 v = 1;
 D(1) = x(1) + x(2) + v - 2;
 D(2) = x(1) - x(2) + v - 1.8;
end
```

Now, I would like to find roots when `v = sort(rand(1,1000))`.  In other words, I would like to iterate over function for each values of `v`.

Comment: ...you know that these are linear equations, right? You don't need `fsolve` to solve those, in fact, that'll be rather slow and quite possibly inaccurate...is `root` an example, or your *real* function to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to modify `root` to accept an additional variable (`v`) and then change the function handle to root to an anonymous function which feeds in the `v` that you want

```
function D = root(x, v)
    D(1) = x(1) + x(2) + v - 2;
    D(2) = x(1) - x(2) + v - 1.8;
end

% Creates a function handle to root using a specific value of v
fun = @(x)root(x, v(k))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case that equation is your *actual* equation (and not a dummy example): that equation is **linear**, meaning, you can solve it for all `v` with a simple [`mldivide`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html):

```
v = sort(rand(1,1000));
x = [1 1; 1 -1] \ bsxfun(@plus, -v, [2; 1.8])
```

And, in case those are *not* your actual equations, you don't need to loop, you can vectorize the whole thing:

```
function x = solver()

    options = optimset('Display'    , 'off',...
                       'MaxFunEvals', 1e5,...
                       'MaxIter'    , 1e4);

    v  = sort(rand(1, 1000));
    x0 = repmat([0 0], numel(v), 1);      
    x  = fsolve(@(x)root(x,v'), x0, options);

end

function D = root(x,v)

    D = [x(:,1) + x(:,2) + v - 2
         x(:,1) - x(:,2) + v - 1.8];

end
```

This may or may not be faster than looping, it depends on your actual equations.

It may be slower because `fsolve` will need to compute a Jacobian of 2000×2000 (4M elements), instead of 2×2, 1000 times (4k elements).

But, it may be faster because the startup cost of `fsolve` can be large, meaning, the overhead of many calls may in fact outweigh the cost of computing the larger Jacobian.

In any case, providing the Jacobian as a second output will speed everything up rather enormously:

```
function solver()

    options = optimset('Display'    , 'off',...
                       'MaxFunEvals', 1e5,...
                       'MaxIter'    , 1e4,...                       
                       'Jacobian'   , 'on');

    v  = sort(rand(1, 1000));
    x0 = repmat([1 1], numel(v), 1);      
    x  = fsolve(@(x)root(x,v'), x0, options);

end

function [D, J] = root(x,v)

    % Jacobian is constant:
    persistent J_out
    if isempty(J_out)
        one   = speye(numel(v));    
        J_out = [+one +one
                 +one -one];
    end

    % Function values at x
    D = [x(:,1) + x(:,2) + v - 2
         x(:,1) - x(:,2) + v - 1.8];

    % Jacobian at x: 
    J = J_out;

end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vvec = sort(rand(1,2));

x0 = [0,0];
for v = vvec,
  fun = @(x) root(v, x);  
  options = optimset('MaxFunEvals',100000,'MaxIter', 10000 );
  x = fsolve(fun, x0, options);
end
```

with function definition:

```
function D = root(v, x)
 D(1) = x(1) + x(2) + v - 2;
 D(2) = x(1) - x(2) + v - 1.8;
end
```